# ErrorVariable parameter working with PowerShell ISE, but not with PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

I am using Powershell and trying to use the -errorvariable parameter to figure out if an execution fails with Invoke-Expression.
This is my code:

```
...

Invoke-Expression ".\ssh\plink.exe -batch $oss_ip -l $oss_usr -pw $oss_psw cd" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -errorvariable badoutput
echo "Badoutput value: $badoutput"
if (!$badoutput){
    write-host "OK" -foreground "green" 
}else{
    write-host "Error" -foreground "red"   
}
```

Plink is a ssh client. Since I am sending an incorrect passwd, the execution fails. (I am printing the $badoutput" for debugging)

This is the result I get if I run the script with PowerShell ISE:

```
Badoutput value: Access denied
Error
```

That was what I was expecting. However, when I ran the same script with Powershell, this is what I got:

```
Access denied
Badoutput value:
OK
```

So, using ISE version the error messages goes to the variable $badoutput but not with standard Powershell.

I am working in a windows 10 Pro machine and my Powershell version (both cases) is:

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      15063  296
```

I would appreciate any help. 
Thanks!

Comment: You're better off using a dedicated library [RenciSSH](http://www.powershelladmin.com/wiki/SSH_from_PowerShell_using_the_SSH.NET_library) - I used this ~ 4 years ago after a very frustrating time with plink

Comment: Thanks for the advice, Raf. If I can't figure out another solution I'll do that.

Comment: Is this a typo? `-errorvariable badoutput`. If not the you forgot the `$` before `badoutput`.

Comment: Could be, but the `-errorvariable` parameter works that way. With `badoutput`  it populates `$badoutput` variable. Well, it should. ty